# preg_replace returns empty string

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Original content:

```
<thead>
<tr style="height: 24px;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 24px;">hello</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 24px;">world</td>
</tr>
```

Content after filter:

```
<thead>
<tr style="height: 24px;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 24px;">hello</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 24px;">world</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

My code:

```
    $reg_exp = "/(<thead>(?:(?:[\n])?.*)*)(<\/tr>)/s"; 
    $replace_with = '$1</tr></thead><tbody>';
    $content = preg_replace($reg_exp, $replace_with, $content);
    return $content;
```

But this return empty string. I can't figure out whats wrong is going on. Any idea?

**Update:**

N.B: I am using this preg_match in a wordpress filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
  $content = str_replace('<ul>','<ul class="list-group">',$content);
  $content = str_replace('<ul >','<ul class="list-group">',$content);
  $content = str_replace('<li>','<li class="list-group-item">',$content);
  $content = str_replace('<li >','<li class="list-group-item">',$content);
  $content = str_replace('</ul>','</ul><div class="gap"> </div>',$content);
  $content = str_replace('<p><img','<img',$content);
  $content = str_replace('<img','<img class="center-img"',$content);
    $reg_exp = "/(^<table.+.(?:[n])?(?:.+)?)(<tbody>)/s";
    $replace_with = '$1<thead>';
    $content = preg_replace($reg_exp, $replace_with, $content);

    $reg_exp = "/(<thead>(?:(?:[\n])?.*)*)(<\/tr>)/s";
    $replace_with = '$1</tr></thead><tbody>';
    $content = preg_replace($reg_exp, $replace_with, $content);
    return $content;
});
```

Comment: Are we parsing valid html here?  Is this the full input string?

Comment: This can offer some html repair: https://3v4l.org/hrmr4  Please clarify your actual/real input data.

Comment: Can we see some more of your code?  This may be a _Typo: Why isn't my code working?_ question.  See proof when I add some of the missing lines of code: https://3v4l.org/ioTHS

Comment: I update my question with full code snippet.

Comment: You should not be hacking away at the dom nodes with `str_replace()`.  I recommend a dom parser.  `^<table` ? Is `<table>` the first tag in your input string?  If this is mostly being done for styling, you should just use css.  Have you checked that `content` is not empty before your last `preg_replace()` call?  Where is the latest point when `$content` is a non-empty string?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing with `[n]`.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer and voting to close as _Off-topic: Why isn't my code working_ because your issue cannot be reproduced [proof](https://3v4l.org/drMZX).  Furthermore, you are using the wrong tools for this job and you may risk mangling your content data.  Providing a proper solution for your greater task is certainly Too Broad and without a realistic/testable input string, I wouldn't know where to begin.  I recommend that you give yourself a crash course in the area of DomDocument with XPath.